# SES receiving emails from all domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses, exim

I created a verified identity with a custom domain `mail.mydomian.com` and added the following DNS records:

```
MX  @   inbound-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com. (Priority: 10)
MX  mail    feedback-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonses.com. (Priority: 10)
TXT @   v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all
TXT mail    v=spf1 include:amazonses.com ~all
```

I configured SES with exim (Cpanel):

Section: AUTH

```
ses_login: 
driver = plaintext 
public_name = LOGIN 
client_send = : username : password
```

Section: TRANSPORTSTART

```
ses_smtp: 
 driver = smtp 
 port = 587 
 hosts_require_auth = * 
 hosts_require_tls = *
```

Section: PREROUTERS

```
send_via_ses: 
 driver = manualroute 
 domains = ! +local_domains  : ! +manualmx_domains
.ifdef SRSENABLED
 # if outbound, and forwarding has been done, use an alternate transport
 transport = ${if eq {$local_part@$domain} \
          {$original_local_part@$original_domain} \
          {ses_smtp} {ses_forwarded_smtp}}
.else
 transport = ses_smtp
.endif
 route_list = * email-smtp.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com;
```

I created a rule set for receiving email with no action.

I can send emails to any email but I can only receive emails from the verified domain so if I send an email from `email@exampl.com` to `info@mydomain.com` I won't receive it. I have to send emails from `mydomain.com` only to receive them.

I try that because I can't forward emails from `info@mydomain.com` to `email@gmail.com` because I get this error:

```
SMTP error from remote mail server after end of data: 554 Message rejected: Email address is not verified. The following identities failed the check in region EU-WEST-1: dmarcreport@microsoft.com, DMARC Aggregate Report <dmarcreport@microsoft.com>
```